# Spark/Scala:Finding count of delimited values in a column eliminating duplicates

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I've a column like

```
+-----------------+----------------------------+
|Race_Track       |             EngineType     |
+----------------------------------------------+
|800-RDUO         |   881,652,EWQ,300x,652,PXZ |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

i should remove one specific value say EWQ and all duplicates like below

```
+-----------------+----------------------------+
|Race_Track       |         EngineType         |
+----------------------------------------------+
|800-RDUO         |   881,300x,652,PXZ         |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

How to achieve this in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired output by combining `split`, `concat_ws` and `array_distinct` as below (assuming `data` is your dataset):

```scala
data = data
  .withColumn("EngineType", array_distinct(
    filter(split(col("EngineType"), ","), x => x.notEqual("EWQ")))
  )
  .withColumn("EngineType", concat_ws(",", col("EngineType")))
```

Final output:

```
+----------+----------------+
|Race_Track|EngineType      |
+----------+----------------+
|800-RDUO  |881,652,300x,PXZ|
+----------+----------------+
```

Good luck!